# Magento2 Social Share Product Page

Tags: magento2, social

I want Functionality in my Product Page as once I shared Product from my PDP (Product Description Page).

After Successful Shared product in Twitter and Instagram, I want Response on my Website, On the Basis of that I can do Further Functionality.

Thanks